# How do I add a polyline segment created with Points to Lines tool to a feature class and apply that feature classes attributes to the line segment?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I am a new ArcMap user transitioning from using AutoCAD.

I have created lines from a point shapefile and have broken them into segments. These segments need to have a specific attribute table attached to them with unique ID's.

I have created all of the line segment types as new polyline feature classes and have the appropriate attribute table correctly formatted for each line type. They are empty at this point.

What I need to do is to take the segments that I have and move them into the various feature classes so each segment has the 'classes attribute info. The ultimate goal is to have these segments correctly attributed for submission to a government agency.

I hope this description makes some sense.

I know that I can 'create features' and trace these segments but I was hoping to find a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan,

If you want to transfer Point attributes to your Polyline features, you can use ArcMap's "Spatial Join" to accomplish this. This runs on all features in both feature classes. The Point feature must "touch" a Polyline feature for the join to take place. There is also an "Attribute Transfer Tool" where you must click the source feature and then click the destination feature for the transfer to occur. No batch mode and no Spatial relationship is required. The "Attribute Transfer Tool" has a dialog to define the field relationaships (what field values will be transfered to the destination feature class).

Comment: Spatial Join may not be  a suitable solution.  If a point feature is touching two line segments, how do you ensure the attribute info. will be assigned to the correct line feature?

Comment: @Artwork21, One way to prevent this is to remove the points that are at the polyline ends before running "Spatial Join". An ArcInfo license is needed. First convert the Polyline end points to a Point feature class, run "Feature Vertices to Point", for Point Type select BOTH_ENDS. Buffer the newly created end_points, say 1 meter. Finally, Erase the original Points that overlap the buffers.

Comment: You method will only work if both cases are meet, 1. secondary point vertices exist between segment start and end vertices, 2. secondary point vertices must have matching attribute info per segment.

Comment: I'm not providing a perfect, end-to-end solution. I'm just providing guidence for the user to mix and match tools, workflow, logic, etc. The user will define what is "good enough".

Comment: Thanks for the information. The 'Spatial Join' tool worked well for me. -Ryan